# Display error of specific forms

Tags: php, laravel

I have two forms on a page (a blade template). Now I want to display form errors so I use:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
@endif
```

Now I have errors on both forms:
[image]

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for laravel validation error. it throw specific error in specific field. You have to use this in every input control.

```
@if ($errors->has('input_name'))<p class="text-danger">
{!!$errors->first('input_name')!!}</p>@endif
```